# My Jenkins Log file is having some garbage value?

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins Log file for my Jenkins job is having some garbage value.

C:\Program Files (x86)\jobs\CA Release Automation\builds\192\log

See the Screenshot below.

[Jenkins Log Garbagevalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WfaP.jpg)

When we view this from Jenkins then no issues when we try to read this log file I am facing the issue.

Comment: that looks like some base64 - decode to see what's that

Comment: How are your users authenticating on Jenkins via LDAP or similar? If so it might be the user token.

Comment: It is just a local instance. I created user and while installing thats all.